# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Estoy tratando de guardar elementos que parseo de un fichero csv en la base de datos y a la hora de parciar dichos elemento me da un error    unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'y no se que hacer.

```
def Procesar(request, pk):  
    fichero = Cargar_Fichero.objects.get(id=pk)
    data = fichero.file
    da = data.name
    da = da[2:]
    try:
        path = MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + da
        ifile = open(path, "r")
        reader = csv.reader(ifile)
        print "Esto es lo que tengo%s" % reader
        list_rows = [row for row in reader]
        i = 0
        for row in list_rows:
            if 'Serial No.' in row:
                break
            i += 1
        valores_bajo_cabecera = list_rows[i + 1:]

        cont = 0
        for row in valores_bajo_cabecera:
            cont += 1
            # reportes= Reportes()
            split = row[0].split(',')
            sn = int(split[0])
            date = split[1]
            log = split[2].strip('="')
            event_co = split[3].strip('="')
            entyti_type = split[4].strip('="')
            entyti_valu = split[5].strip('="')
            action = split[6].strip('="')
            computer = split[7].strip('="')
            user = split[8].strip('="')
            user_role = split[9].strip('="')
            Reportes.objects.create(
            id_fichero=fichero,
                serial=sn,
                day=date,
                log_source=log,
                event_code=event_co,
                entyti_type=entyti_type,
                entyti_value=entyti_valu,
                action=action,
                computer=computer,
                user=user,
                user_role=user_role
            )

            w = action.split(' ')
            if 'change' in action:
                estado = w[-1]
            elif 'assigned' in action:
                estado = w[-1]
            else:
                estado ="%s %s" % (w[-2], w[-1])

            print(estado)


            try:

            # if Resultado.objects.get(nombre =user):
                resultado = Mostrar_Resultado.objects.get(nombre=user)#
                resultado.alarma_asignada += 1
                resultado.fecha=date

                if estado== 'Available':
                    resultado.disponible_Fr +=1
                elif estado=='as Fraudulent ':
                    resultado.fraude +=1
                elif estado=='Non Fraudulent':
                    resultado.no_fraude+=1

                else:
                    alarma=Alarmas.objects.get(nombre=user)
                    if estado=='was deleted':
                        alarma.eliminada +=1

                    elif estado =='to Investigation':
                        alarma.investigada +=1
                    else:
                        alarma.asignada +=1

                resultado.alm_inv= resultado.fraude+resultado.no_fraude+resultado.disponible_Fr
                resultado.bajo_inv_cierre=resultado.alarma_asignada-(resultado.fraude+resultado.no_fraude+resultado.disponible_Fr)
                resultado.por_ciento_fr=''
                resultado.uso_sistema=''
                resultado.save()
            except Mostrar_Resultado.DoesNotExist:
            # else:
                resultado = Mostrar_Resultado()

                resultado.nombre=user
                resultado.fecha=date
                resultado.alarma_asignada = 1

                if estado=='Available':
                    resultado.disponible_Fr =1

                elif estado=='as Fraudulent':
                    resultado.fraude=1

                elif estado=='Non Fraudulent':
                    resultado.no_fraude=1
                else:
                    alarma=Alarmas()
                    if estado=='was deleted':
                        alarma.eliminada =1

                    elif estado =='to Investigation':
                        alarma.investigada =1
                    else:
                        alarma.asignada =1
                resultado.alm_inv= resultado.fraude+resultado.no_fraude+resultado.disponible_Fr
                resultado.bajo_inv_cierre=resultado.alarma_asignada-(resultado.fraude+resultado.no_fraude+resultado.disponible_Fr)
                resultado.por_ciento_fr=''
                resultado.uso_sistema=''
                resultado.save()
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SOes, ¿puedes mostrar el error completo?

Comment: No me muestra Traceback (most recent call last) porque lo puse dentro de un try caht y lanza este tipo de excepcion:  "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Python, `NoneType` es el tipo de dato para el objeto `None` que es un objeto que justamente indica la ausencia de valor. Por tal motivo, no puedes usarlo con otro objeto con el operador + (la operación no está definida para este tipo de datos).

Pero, **¿por qué me sucede esto?**
En tus líneas:

```
resultado.alm_inv= resultado.fraude+resultado.no_fraude+resultado.disponible_Fr
resultado.bajo_inv_cierre=resultado.alarma_asignada-(resultado.fraude+resultado.no_fraude+resultado.disponible_Fr)
```

Alguno de los operandos puede no estar asignado debido a que en los if que tienes por encima, no contemplas un valor inicial para los mismos (probablemente deban ser 0).